# How to resolve the error I get when creating a subtheme of the Drupal Aurora theme?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I get an error when I try to create a subtheme of Drupal's [Aurora theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/aurora).

I'm following Aurora's directions and in Terminal, here's the error I get:

```
MY-MacBook-Pro:aurora myname$ compass create aurorasub -r aurora --using aurora
LoadError on line ["45"] of    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- aurora
```

Run with --trace to see the full backtrace.

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what could have caused this, although normally it is because the gem is not appropriately installed (or the "aurora" gem is installed, not the "compass-aurora" gem). BUT I can say that this should not be an issue anymore, as the creation of sub-themes has been moved to a Yeoman generator.

You can see the aurora generator here: https://github.com/Snugug/generator-aurora

OR

There is a generic generator that has feature parity with the aurora one here: https://github.com/frontend-united/generator-drupal-theme